# ArrayBuffer memory leak and Firefox memory tool

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer

I'm trying to debug a memory leak through the usage of Firefox memory tool.

What I was able to find is that an ArrayBuffer object keeps increasing its size second after second. This object is used to receive audio/video data. If not managed, this behaviour results into a out of memory condition in which the computer literally freezes. The feeling is that the object is not properly released or cleared.

Through the memory tool, however, is not possible to go back to the exact variable that is causing the issue. I've checked also with the "Record call stacks" option and grouping by call stacks, but unfortunately - exactly in corrispondence of the aforementioned element - the tool says "(no stack available)".

Does anyone know how would it be possible to retrieve additional information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

After all, check "Record call stacks".

1. Take a snapshot.
2. wait a while, do stuff.
3. take a second snapshot.

Select compare tool and select the snapshots

It will calculate the diff and show you the call stack and their memory consuming difference.